# Select-Object doesn't return object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The following code returns expected list.

```
$groups = ps | group Name

$groups | Sort-Object Name | % { 
    $g = $_.Group | measure PM -Sum;
    New-Object psobject -Property @{ Name2 = $_.Name; Count = $g.Count; Sum = $g.Sum }
}
```

However, the following script, which use `select` to create custom object, returns nothing? I read that `Select-object` is another way to create `PSObject`?

```
$groups = ps | group Name

$groups | Sort-Object Name | % { 
    $g = $_.Group | measure PM -Sum;
    select -Property @{ Name = 'Name'; expression = { $_.Name }},
                     @{ Name = 'Count'; expression = { $g.Count }},
                     @{ Name = 'Sum'; expression = { $g.Sum }}
}
```

**Update:**
Tested it on Powershell 2.0 and 3.0. They behave the same.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS H:\> $groups = ps | group Name
PS H:\>
PS H:\> $groups | Sort-Object Name | % {
>>     $g = $_.Group | measure PM -Sum;
>>     # New-Object psobject -Property @{ Name2 = $_.Name; Count = $g.Count; Sum = $g.Sum }
>>     select -Property @{ Name = 'Name'; expression = { $_.Name }}, @{ Name = 'Count'; expression = { $g.Count }}, @{ Name = 'Sum'; expression = { $g.Sum }}
>> }
>>
PS H:\>
```

Comment: Tested in PS 2.0 and it works just fine.

Comment: I tested on three machines (two 3.0 and one 2.0) and the second script returned nothing on all three machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` statement is a standalone command not receiving any input from the pipeline since it is inside a `foreach` block. You, have to pass the current pipeline object `$_` to the select statement for it to do anything:

```
$groups | Sort-Object Name | % { 
    $g = $_.Group | measure PM -Sum;
    $_ | select -Property @{ Name = 'Name'; expression = { $_.Name }},
                     @{ Name = 'Count'; expression = { $g.Count }},
                     @{ Name = 'Sum'; expression = { $g.Sum }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Select consider going this route:

```
$groups = ps | group Name

$groups | Sort-Object Name | 
    select -Property @{ Name = 'Name'; expression = { $_.Name }},
                     @{ Name = 'Count'; expression = { $_.Group.Count }},
                     @{ Name = 'Sum'; expression = { $_.Group | measure PM -Sum | Select -Expand Sum }}
```

I removed the ForEach, and moved the creation of $g to just be the expression for Sum.